# IAsyncEnumerable cannot be used for parameter of type IEnumerable

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have entities, service and view models. I use the service models in the services and in the service I map from entity to the service model and I return `IQueryable<UserServiceModel>` and I use the service in the controller but when I try to materialize the result and map it to the view model with Select it throw exception:

> ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[TestDriveServiceModel]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestDriveServiceModel]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestDriveServiceModel] ToList[TestDriveServiceModel](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestDriveServiceModel])'
>   Parameter name: arg0

```
// the service map from entities to service models and returns them
// userServiceModels is the result of the service
// Here the error is thrown
var viewModel = await userServiceModels.Select(usm => new UserViewModel()
{
    TestDrivesCount = usm.TestDrives.Count()
}).ToListAsync();
```

```
public class UserServiceModel : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TestDriveServiceModel> TestDrives { get; set; } = new List<TestDriveServiceModel>();
    }
```

```
public class TestDriveServiceModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string CarId { get; set; }
        public CarServiceModel Car { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public UserServiceModel User { get; set; }

        public string StatusId { get; set; }
        public StatusServiceModel Status { get; set; }

        public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class User : IdentityUserEntity
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TestDriveEntity> TestDrives { get; set; } = new List<TestDriveEntity>();
    }
```

```
public class TestDriveEntity
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CarId { get; set; }
        public BaseCarEntity Car { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public User UserEntity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string StatusId { get; set; }
        public Status StatusEntity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: [IAsyncEnumerable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=netcore-3.0) was added in .NET Core *3* and C# 8. It's not used by EF Core 2.2. Where is this exception thrown? Please post the *actual* code that throws this exception and the *full* exception text returned from `Exception.ToString()`. The full text contains the call stack and any inner exceptions.

Comment: In any case the error complains about an invalid argument to the [List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) constructor. There's no such code in the code you posted. Please post the code that actually throws this exception.